# Permissions on .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-ec2, permissions

I tried to edit .htaccess file via sftp on filezila (ppk file and etc) and it says i dont have permissions to edit\upload.
I have wordpress bitnami on aws ec2.
Can you help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a place to ask _programming_ related questions. This appears to be a hosting or configuration issue. Please consult your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the ftp user does have permissions to edit the files. If not then you have to change the ownership of the files/folders to the ftp user. You may also have to add your FTP user to the group of your web server user.